# Problem in Typeorm EventSubscriber & Postgres AfterInsert

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have a big problem with EventSubscribers of `typeorm` & `PostgreSQL`.

I need to set `Notification` for a newly created `Entity` inside the `AfterInsert` event on `TypeormEventSubscriber` but, when I try to set the relations there is nothing inserted into the database to do that.

```
# Output of event.entity

Entity: {
  id: 34,
}

# It seems everything is ok and the record inserted but it's not.
```

Typeorm runs every query including the event hooks query inside a transaction as it seems, until every query is not done correctly, nothing is inserted into the database, which means I can not create relations in events even in `AfterInserted` because nothing is written into tables.

there is no other solution for this use case?
I can write the code after entity saved within my service but, not what I'm looking for.

thanks...

`TYPEORM`:`POSTGRESQL` Set relations on event hooks